# Find all analytic function in $\{z:|z|<1\}$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all analytic functions in $\{z:|z|<1\}$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Apply the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) to $f$ and $g$, where $g(z)=z^3$.